# Android: Remove Downloaded file shortcut from "Downloads" folder

Tags: java, android, shortcut, android-download-manager

In my code I used to download apk, use it and then remove it. But after removing it, Apk is removed only from internal storage (internal storage/android/data//files/download) but it still is in My Files/Downloads folder. 
How can I remove this shortcut/view from My Files/Downloads folder programmatically, or how to prevent saving it into this folder?

Downloading code:

```
final String destination = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + FORWARD_SLASH + TMP_APK_NAME;
final Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);

//set downloadmanager
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

//set destination
request.setDestinationUri(uri);

// get download service and enqueue file
final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
manager.enqueue(request);
```

Deletion code:

```
//Delete update file if exists
final File file = new File(destination);
if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
}
```

Comment: Check `file.exists()` returned value. I think you're getting `false` here instead `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) 
enqueue will return a long value which represents the id of this file in the download folder. Store this value in a variable

```
long fileId = manager.enqueue(request);
```

then use this value to remove it from downdloads

```
manager.remove(fileId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try with this way also - Hope it will work. 
As the `DownloadManager` can download the file in this `uri` so you may delete with that `uri`.

```
// Delete update file if exists
File file = new File(uri.getPath());
if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
}
```

Comment: It didn't help. Shortcut still is in DOWNLOADS folder. User can click on it and re-download. So it isn't the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
final String destination = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + FORWARD_SLASH + TMP_APK_NAME;
final Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);

File file = new File(uri.getPath());
if (file.exists()) { // if your file exit 
  file.delete();
}
```

make sure you have write external storage permission

Comment: make sure you have  write external storage permission

Comment: It didn't help. Shortcut still is in DOWNLOADS folder. User can click on it and re-download. So it isn't the solution for me.